# How to pass 2 or more variables using @PathParam in spring mvc? and suppose if I want to test it out using postman how to do that?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, postman, jparepository

I'm trying to fetch value from db using JPA repository method

`product findByIdNumberOrCifNumber(String idNumber , String cifNumber);`

service class logic:-

```
public ResponseModel FindByCivIDOrCifNumber(String idNumber,String cifNumber) {
    ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
    Optional<product> civId = Optional.ofNullable(productRepos.findByIdNumber(idNumber));
    if (civId.isPresent()) {
        responseModel.setResponse(productRepos.findByIdNumberOrCifNumber(idNumber,cifNumber));
    } else {
        errorModel errorModel1 = new errorModel();
enter image description here        errorModel1.setErrorCode(productConstant.INVALID_REQUEST);
        errorModel1.setErrorDescription("Requested Civil Id or CifNUmber is not present");
        responseModel.setErrorModel(errorModel1);
    }
    return responseModel;

}
```

controller class:-

```
@GetMapping("/getByCifNoOrGetByIdNo")
    public ResponseModel getProductByCifNoOrGetByIdNo(@RequestParam String idNumber,@RequestParam String cifNumber )  {
        return productService.FindByCivIDOrCifNumber(idNumber,cifNumber);
    }
```

post man:-

kindly help me out how to make it work:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an answer to pass two or more path variables and test it with postman, you can try this.

```
@GetMapping("/api/mapping-name/{variable1}/{variable2}")
```

Here you will be getting two path variables which you can access by the syntax

```
@PathVariable("variable1") datatype variableName
```

Now in postman request url you can simply give the respective url, lets say:

```
https://localhost8080/api/mapping-name/:variable1/:variable2
```

which automaticaly will give you a key value section in the path variables section in the params with prepopulated key names as per the name you have  given. In this case variable1 & variable2.

Give the respective value and it should work.